# how can i sign in ftp client(winscp) as root?

Tags: root, winscp

I use WinSCP as an FTP client.  I have access as a normal user, But I want to sign in as a root, How can I do it? Do I Need the same credentials or different?

Comment: So FTP or SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

FTP protocol does not allow this.
The SFTP and SCP protocols allow for this, but the actual method is platform dependent.

You cannot use sudo from the terminal, so you need to specify it as the
"Shell" for the session.
This will also require configuration changes in the server.

For the exact details, see the WinSCP FAQ
[How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)